# Enforcing that user-generated HTML cannot break out of a containing element

Tags: html, xss

Suppose that I have a Web application that wants to allow for users to use markup in their posts (as Stack Exchange itself does).

Stripping out dangerous elements is not too difficult.  There are open-source libraries to do it in many languages.  However, not all of them ensure that the HTML will not break out of a containing element.

Under what circumstances can properly nested HTML break out of a containing element?  What are best practices to ensure that cannot happen?